# Response.Redirect to next preceding sibling with umbraco.NodeFactory GetNodeByXpath from .net Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, umbraco

I want to redirect customers from one page to its first preceding sibling from .NET usercontrol. This is my code but I get exception "$currentPage/preceding-siblings::* [@isDoc][1] **has an invalid token**."

```
Node sibling = Node.GetNodeByXpath(@"$currentPage/preceding-siblings::* [@isDoc][1]");
if (sibling != null)
    Response.Redirect(umbraco.library.NiceUrl(sibling.Id));
```

As of course currentPage is not a defined parameter in .net usercontrol, I thought about removing it, so, I wrote this

```
Node sibling = Node.GetNodeByXpath(@"/preceding-siblings::* [@isDoc][1]");
if (sibling != null)
    Response.Redirect(umbraco.library.NiceUrl(sibling.Id));
```

I tried more ways, nothing works. I can't figure out what is wrong in my code, any ideas! is there any other way to do that. Note, I must do it from within .net usercontrol not xslt. Thanks in advace

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this, i don't know whether its the right method.

Take the children of root node and save their ids in an integer list. Then you can find the preceding node of the current node from the list.

Comment: I thought about that approach but I am sure there is a faster and more straight forward approach. I will wait a bit longer and see if we can have more ideas.

Comment: @m.othman: yes exactly, please post this in umbraco forum also, more people will look there..

Comment: The solution on Umbraco forum

[http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/30562-ResponseRedirect-to-next-preceding-sibling-with-umbracoNodeFactory-GetNodeByXpath-from-net-Usercontrol?p=0#comment113443]